# Is it possible to use caret package parallel processing with SQL Server R Services (revoscaleR) parallel option?

Tags: sql-server, r, parallel-processing, microsoft-r

Well the title says it all,

the caret package allows trainControl using parallel processing, and SQL Server R Services as parallel computing capabilities offered by microsoft R implementation, but I don't know if the two are compatibles.

Comment: Just about anything you can do in open source R, you can also do in Microsoft R. What is your exact use case?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question correctly but to parallelize training, you would need to use one of the revoscaleR functions starting with rx. You can parallelize scoring in sp_execute_external_script in SQL Server by using the parameter @parallel = 1. If your input query to the R script runs with a parallel execution plan, then you should get parallel execution on the R script too.